# Collision probability of ObjectId vs UUID in a large distributed system

Tags: mongodb, guid, uuid, rfc4122

Considering that an UUID rfc 4122 (16 bytes) is much larger than a MongoDB ObjectId (12 bytes), I am trying to find out how their collision probability compare.

I know that is something around **quite unlikely**, but in my case most ids will be generated within a large number of mobile clients, not within a limited set of servers. **I wonder if in this case, there is a justified concern**.

Compared to the normal case where all ids are generated by a small number of clients:

- It might take months to detect a collision since the document creation
- IDs are generated from a much larger client base
- Each client has a lower ID generation rate

Comment: Why are you allowing mobile clients to create the ObjectIds, or any permanent Id if you're concerned data integrity?

Comment: The clients might be offline and store information which might not be synced for a long time. I do not want to force a 100% online mobile app

Comment: @WiredPrairie most **client** library implementations create the `_id` value by default. Not saying it is a "good idea" to connect directly. But "ObjectId" generation is perfectly valid.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't build or design a system that allowed clients to do this. I'd assign them temporary Ids when offline. I'd consider no different than expecting a client doesn't directly write to MongoDb without going through a data validation layer.

Comment: @NeilLunn-I know most clients do that by default. An offline client could still create them, but they would need to be validated before inserting into the collection.

Comment: I would like to avoid not using ObjectId since MongoDB optimizes this data type. Sometimes it even required them the past (Aggregation framework?)

Comment: I really like the content from @mnemosyn, if for not much else than it does make the **monotonic** point that is inherent in the design of the spec. As such I also found this a *fair* question to ask and a very valid consideration for others to see in the future. The overall point says the "collision factor" is a like more than "quite unlikely".

Comment: All this made me reconsider the role of UUIDs for offline clients. @WiredPrairie comment on temporal ids waiting for validation layer seems to be better future proof than just relying on UUIDs, but also such a pain to implement... well, partition tolerance was never a piece of cake. Thanks for the "birthday problem" mention.

Comment: @SystematicFrank - Why not allow the clients to cache the entry with their own id system, then when they're back on line, write the cache to the remote and let the remote decide the id, that way no collision risk. I don't think there's a way to guarantee no collisions.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> in my case most ids will be generated within a large number of mobile clients, not within a limited set of servers. I wonder if in this case, there is a justified concern.

That sounds like very bad architecture to me. Are you using a two-tier architecture? Why would the mobile clients have direct access to the db? Do you really want to rely on network-based security?

Anyway, some deliberations about the collision probability:

Neither UUID nor ObjectId rely on their sheer size, i.e. both are not random numbers, but they follow a scheme that tries to systematically reduce collision probability. In case of [ObjectIds, their structure is](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/):

- 4 byte seconds since unix epoch
- 3 byte machine id
- 2 byte process id
- 3 byte counter

This means that, contrary to UUIDs, ObjectIds are monotonic (except within a single second), which is probably their most important property. Monotonic indexes will cause the B-Tree to be filled more efficiently, it allows paging by id and allows a 'default sort' by id to make your cursors stable, and of course, they carry an easy-to-extract timestamp. These are the optimizations you should be aware of, and they can be huge.

As you can see from the structure of the other 3 components, collisions become very likely if you're doing > 1k inserts/s on a single process (not really possible, not even from a server), or if the number of machines grows past about 10 (see birthday problem), or if the number of processes on a single machine grows too large (then again, those aren't random numbers, but they are truly unique on a machine, but they must be shortened to two bytes).

Naturally, for a collision to occur, they must match in *all* these aspects, so even if two machines have the same machine hash, it'd still require a client to insert with the same counter value in the exact same second and the same process id, but yes, these values could collide.

Comment: We did this again. Jinx!

Comment: Yeah... If I hadn't taken the time to grab that coffee... :(

Comment: The mobile clients will not have direct access to the database, indeed, they can run even without a connection to it. However each mobile client will have to upload documents to the main database sooner or later.

Comment: To be fair I'm sure I poured wine in my time-zone. Doesn't matter as long as the point gets across.

Comment: There are perfectly valid cases for generating IDs from a client, and it doesn't imply access to the database at all.  If you're doing this you definitely must not use ObjectIds, since it will have serious collision issues if you have tens or hundreds of thousands of clients generating them.  I don't trust ObjectIds, since it's too easy to find cases, even if they require specific conditions, where collisions can occur.

Comment: @mnemosyn Helpful answer, however, I don't understand why 1k inserts/s per process can already be a problem. You would think that the counter increments by 1 on each "request" within the same second and resets to zero at the beginning of the next second. But with 3 bytes, you can represent much larger numbers than 1k. What am I missing here?

Comment: What scares me is that once two instances collide, there suddenly exists a very significant chance of collisions (esp. during batch processing) that does not go away until one of the instances goes away. This is one of the problems I built [DistributedId](https://github.com/TheArchitectDev/Architect.Identities#distributed-ids) and [DistributedId128](https://github.com/TheArchitectDev/Architect.Identities#distributedid128) to avoid. (At the time of writing, I have not seen an implementation of the algorithms for other platforms than .NET, though.)

Answer (score 17):

Let's look at the spec for "ObjectId" from the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#overview):

> ### Overview
>
> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:
>
> - a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> - a 3-byte machine identifier,
> - a 2-byte process id, and
> - a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

So let us consider this in the **context** of a "mobile client".

> **Note:** The context here does **not** mean using a "direct" connection of the "mobile client" to the database. That should **not** be done. But the "_id" generation **can** be done quite simply.

So the points:

1. Value for the "seconds since epoch". That is going to be fairly random per request. So minimal collision impact just on that component. Albeit in "seconds".
2. The "machine identifier". So this **is** a *different* client generating the `_id` value. This is removing possibility of further "collision".
3. The "process id". So where that is accessible to seed ( and it should be ) then the generated `_id` has **more** chance of avoiding collision.
4. The "random value". So another "client" somehow managed to generate all of the same values as above and **still** managed to generate the **same** random value.

Bottom line is, if **that** is not a convincing enough argument to digest, then simply provide your own "uuid" entries as the "primary key" values.

But IMHO, that should be a *fair* convincing argument to consider that the collision aspects here are **very** broad. To say the least.

The **full** topic is probably just a little "too-broad". But I hope this moves consideration a bit more away from "Quite unlikely" and on to something a little more concrete.

Comment: I don’t see how this answers the question about collision probability. It just unpacks the data layout and uses bold formatting to suggest things. I guess one often answer more concretely by way of analogies like “a collision given X setup is less likely than being hit by lightning Y times in a single night and be attacked by a pack of wolfs.” ;)