# MongoDB C# Driver - Return an Id of type string from controller

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following model:

```
public class Student
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the this endpoint in my controller:

```
public IEnumerable<Student> GetAll()
{
    MongoCollection<Student> collection = Db.GetCollection<Student>("students");
    List<Student> students = collection.AsQueryable().ToList();
    return students;
}
```

The GetAll() endpoint which is exposed to the public, returns a Student which has an Id of type ObjectId, which is not a standart type. I would rather want it to be of type string.

But if I change it to string, I can't use the .ToList(), getting an error like so:
**"Cannot deserialize string from BsonType ObjectId"**

I know I can solve this using some projections and conversions, but they will add some ugly and noisy code to the CRUD methods.

What is the best way to keep **Id in string type** exposed to the public and still be able to use the c# driver's api?

Comment: If you want to use a string instead of ObjectId, you need to change the type from ObjectId to String in Mongo directly too. If you explore the data, with MongoVue for example, you'll see the data type is ObjectId. Ids can be anything (even complex objects), but you need the same type in the DB and in the class definition.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: I beg to differ. You can register custom serializers, and it's quite common. Also, the C# driver comes with built-in serializers for tons of types, many of which are unknown to mongo, including `decimal`, `Stack`, `Dictionary`, `IPAddress` and even `CultureInfo`, see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/tree/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Serializers Using strings in the DB *will* impact performance and storage

Answer (score 2):

The controller should do the conversion. Generally, controllers should communicate using DTOs with the outside world:

```
public IEnumerable<StudentReadDTO> GetAll()
{
    MongoCollection<Student> collection = Db.GetCollection<Student>("students");
    List<Student> students = collection.AsQueryable().ToList();
    return students.Select(p => AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<StudentReadDTO>(p));
} 

// this DTO should be used for POST and PUT (i.e where there is no id or the id 
// is part of the URL) - after all, it doesn't make sense to send the id from the
// client to the server
public class StudentDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// this should be used by reading operations, where the id is read from the server
// inheritance in DTOs is a source of confusion and can be painful, but this trivial
// type of inheritance will be fine
public class StudentReadDTO : StudentDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

This example uses [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org) to do a convention-based mapping between `Student` and `StudentDTO`, but you do the mapping yourself if you like.

In the database layer, it makes sense to use `ObjectId` because of [its properties.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22607171/257786)

Comment: Exactly how I was going to answer :)

Comment: Will AutoMapper knows how to automatically convert string to ObjectId, and the other way around ? And also, will those conversions (with or without AutoMapper) could have an impact on performance? (This controller is going to be used in an environment with intensive read/write operations)

Comment: Yes, it will, because it automatically finds a matching constructor. You can customize the conversion if necessary, though. The AutoMapper documentation is quite good. Mapping a few bytes from one representation to another in RAM should be in the 3-digit nanosecond range on commodity h/w. That's nothing compared to accessing the network stack which will be in the order of milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Although the suggested answer by @mnemosyn using AutoMapper looks like a great solution and a good pattern to handle those kind of cases, in the case of the MongoDB C# driver you have a dedicated solution and can simply put the following attribute and you are done:

```
public class Student
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

(I got this solution from the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/t6AGPcBWa_M) of MongoDB)