# MongoDB generating UUID

Tags: mongodb, uuid

Is the best solution to use UUID() function in db script in order to generate UUIDs for column or there are better solutions? Because when I tried to test it on my db it generated guids but they are similar:

```
fb55b9f1-dc80-11e5-9332-000c2931ded6
fb55bba4-dc80-11e5-9332-000c2931ded6
```

Only first 8 symbols different. So what should be better solution for this ?

I used this script: `UPDATE Table set GUID = uuid();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of UUID/GUID is to be unique in your `global` context, what now is your database. The fact that they are similar shouldn't bother you. I would stick with the `mongo`'s implementation just because it is simple to use, nothing external is required, and all `uuid`-s should implement the [same standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

If you're interested in the probability of duplicates check out these questions:[Collision probability of ObjectId vs UUID in a large distributed system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606364/collision-probability-of-objectid-vs-uuid-in-a-large-distributed-system),  [Possibility of duplicate Mongo ObjectId's being generated in two different collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677237/possibility-of-duplicate-mongo-objectids-being-generated-in-two-different-colle).